# Как в Selectmenu jQuery UI добавить html

Tags: javascript, jquery, веб-программирование, jquery-ui

Когда создаю выпадающий список через плагин *Selectmenu jQuery UI* и вписываю внутрь тега `option` другие теги (мне нужно, чтобы пункты меню были двухстрочными, и каждая строка имела свой стиль, а не просто текст), то эти теги вырезаются, и в итоге в элементе списка оказывается только строка текста.

Как сделать, чтобы в стилизованном через *Selectmenu* выпадающем списке каждый элемент списка состоял бы из двух разных строк с разными стилями?